# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in Angular 11

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I have an error in my Angular Application "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4040/api/menus' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." This is for side bar menu items, load when user logging into the application which get by Backend api. I have add CORS policies but it still existing. Also I have shown multiple menu aip in Browser network only one menu link have **"OPTIONS"** and rest of getting 500 status error Code with **"GET" method**.I try api in Postman and it working fine not in browser. I have attached the images for the references. Here's my code

**side-bar.component.html**

```
  <div class="h-100 w-100 position-relative">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100px; display: flex;">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 mt-2 d-xl-none d-lg-none" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100;">
      <fa-icon class="browse fa-lg cursor-pointer" [icon]="backArrow"  (click)="toggleSideBar()"></fa-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 pl-5 pr-5 pt-3 text-center">
      <img src="/assets/img/logo.png"  class="img-fluid w-75" alt="Logo">
      <p class="text-center">
        <small>Azbil Singapore</small>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="height: calc(100vh - 140px); overflow-y: auto;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 pl-0 pr-0">
      <ul class="menu top-level" *ngIf="menuDataSet && menuDataSet.length > 0">
        <li *ngFor="let item of menuDataSet">
          <span class="pl-3 pt-2 pr-3 pb-2 d-block menu-item" (click)="onMainItemSelected(item.url)" [ngClass]="[item.subMenus.length != 0 ? 'inactive' : '', mainItemURL == item.url ? 'active': '']" [routerLink]="item.url == '#' ? [] : [item.url]" [innerHtml]="showProgress(item.item)"></span>
          <ul *ngIf="item.subMenus.length > 0">
            <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.subMenus">
              <span class="pl-5 pt-2 pr-3 pb-2 d-block menu-item sub-menu-item" (click)="onSubItemSelected(subItem.url)" [ngClass]="{'active': subItemURL == subItem.url}" [routerLink]="subItem.url" [innerHtml]="showProgress(subItem.item)"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <p class="text-center footer-version" (click)="openVersionModel()">Version {{version}}</p>
</div>
```

**Side-bar.component.ts**

```
  export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit,OnChanges {

  private userName: string;
  private users: any[];
  public menuItemList = [];

  menuItems: any = [];
  backArrow = faArrowLeft;
  isSideMenuActive: boolean;
  version: string;
  mainItemURL: string;
  subItemURL: string;
  roleName: string;
  menuDataSet: any;
  

  arrowDown = faChevronCircleDown;
  arrowUp = faChevronCircleUp;

  constructor(
    private initialService: InitialService,
    private dataService: HttpService,
    private endPoints: InitialService,
    private headerService: HeaderService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private router: Router,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private auth: AuthService
    ) {
    this.headerService.isSideBarActive.subscribe(isActive => {
      this.isSideMenuActive = isActive;
    });
    this.version = this.initialService.getVersion();
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.menuDataSet) {
      console.log('change');
      this.roleName = localStorage.getItem('roleName');
      this.getRoles();
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.roleName = localStorage.getItem('roleName');
    this.getRoles();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.userName = localStorage.getItem('user');
      this.roleName = localStorage.getItem('roleName');
      
      this.getRoles();
      //this.getUsers();
      this.auth.getMenus().subscribe((res: any)=>{
        alert(res);
        this.menuItems = res
        res.forEach((e: any) => {
          // alert(e);
        },
          (error: any) =>console.log("Error", error));
      })
      
  
    }

  getRoles() {    
    this.getMenu();
  }


  onMainItemSelected(item: string) {
    this.subItemURL = '';
    if (item != '#') {
      this.mainItemURL = item;
    }
  }
  onSubItemSelected(item: string) {
    this.mainItemURL = '';
    if (item != '#') {
      this.subItemURL = item;
    }
  }

  toggleSideBar() {
    this.headerService.toggleSideBar();    
  }

  showProgress(item: any) {
    switch (item) {
      default:
        return item;
    }
  }

  openVersionModel() {
    const modal = this.modalService.open(VersionComponent, { size: 'lg', scrollable: true});
    modal.componentInstance.title = "Locations";
  }

  public getMenu(){
    const details = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    console.log("token");
    console.log(details);
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + details);
    const headers = { headers: header };
    console.log('responseOK');
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:4200/api/menus', headers).subscribe(data => {
      this.menuDataSet = data;
      console.log(this.menuDataSet);
    });
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
getMenus(){
  const details  = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + details);
  const headers = { headers: header };
  return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:4040/api/menus', headers);
}
```

[This the OPTIONS with working api but i don't have any OPTIONS method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhjda.png)

[Error with 404.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj70V.png)[Error with 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwSvv.png)

Any opinion and solution why I'm having this?

Comment: Either set up CORS on the backend correctly, or use [Angular proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: I use this for CORS ` services.AddCors(option =>
   {
    option.AddPolicy(
     name: "AllowOrigin",
      builder =>
      {
       builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
      });
   }); `